# Confusion related to universal hashing

Tags: math, hash, hashtable, universal-hashing

I was reading this [video lecture](https://class.coursera.org/algo-004/lecture/68) related to universal hashing. It shows the example of hashing IP addresses. Each IP address consists of 4, 32 bit integers, (x1,x2,x3,x4) with any xi having the maximum value of 255.

The tutorial says that the size of the hash table should be greater than 255 or any of the xis. Why is it so?

Comment: Don't see how this is related to universal hashing. Better to ask the lecturer.

Answer (score 0):

(For those of you who haven't seen the video, this comes up around 20:45).

The class of functions defined this way are functions of the form

> h<sub>a</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, x<sub>4</sub>) = a<sub>1</sub> x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> x<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub> x<sub>3</sub> + a<sub>4</sub> x<sub>4</sub> (mod n)

where n is the number of buckets, each x<sub>i</sub> is in the range 0 to n - 1, each a<sub>i</sub> is in the range 0 to n - 1, and n is prime.

Your question is why all the x<sub>i</sub>'s have to be less than n. The reason has to do with the proof that this family of hash functions is universal. As Tim explains in the video, one of the ways that you can prove that the hash function is universal is to consider two distinct inputs (call them x and y). That means that they have to differ in some component, and the idea is to assume without loss of generality that they differ in the fourth component. That is, x<sub>4</sub> ≠ y<sub>4</sub>. With a bit of math, under that assumption, you can show that the probability that you get a collision is equal to the probability that this statement is true:

> a<sub>4</sub>(x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub>) = a<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) + a<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>) + a<sub>3</sub>(x<sub>3</sub> - y<sub>3</sub>) (mod n)

Here, since we chose the hash function randomly, all of the a<sub>i</sub>'s are random. The key insight is that if you treat a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, and a<sub>3</sub> as fixed values, then the right-hand side of this equation just some fixed number k. You're then interested in the probability that

> a<sub>4</sub>(x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub>) = k (mod n)

Because we're assuming that n > x<sub>4</sub>, that n > y<sub>4</sub>, that x<sub>4</sub> ≠ y<sub>4</sub>, and that n is prime. This tells us two very important facts:

1. **x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> ≠ 0 mod n.** This is the main reason that we need n to be larger than the x<sub>i</sub>'s. We'll see why in a minute.
2. **x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> is coprime with n.** Why is that? Well, we know that n is a prime number. Since n > x<sub>4</sub> and n > y<sub>4</sub>, we know that x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> must be strictly between n-1 and -(n-1). Because we're assuming that n is prime, there are non nontrivial divisors of n in that range, so x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> and n are coprime.

To see why these facts matter, let's consider two cases for k. First, it's possible that k = 0. In that case, in what case will a<sub>4</sub>(x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub>) = k (mod n)? Since x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> ≠ 0, we know that this only happens if a<sub>4</sub> = 0. Since a<sub>4</sub> takes on a uniformly-random value in the range 0 through n-1 inclusive, the probability that we get a collision in this case is 1/n.

Next, suppose that k ≠ 0. In that case, what has to happen for a<sub>4</sub>(x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub>) = k (mod n) to be true? Well, we know that x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> ≠ 0, so it must have a multiplicative inverse modulo n because x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> is coprime with n. In fact, it has exactly one multiplicative inverse. The only possible choice of a<sub>4</sub> that will cause this to be true is the choice where a<sub>4</sub> is the multiplicative inverse of x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> modulo n multiplied by k. There's exactly one choice of number in the range 0 through n-1 that works, so the probability of picking it is 1/n.

Notice that if x<sub>4</sub> - y<sub>4</sub> were equal to zero modulo n, the above reasoning wouldn't work. In the first case, *every* choice of a<sub>4</sub> would cause a collision, so the collision probability would be 1. In the second case, *no* choice of a<sub>4</sub> could cause a collision, so the collision probability would be 0. These conditions would invalidate the proof.

Hope this helps!